# Solve the equation $4x^3+13x^2-14x=3-\sqrt{15x+9}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I ran into this problem:
$$4x^3+13x^2-14x=3-\sqrt{15x+9}$$

It makes no sense to square it. I thought it was necessary to make a replacement. What kind of substitution?
First of all, the root gets in the way, so you have to make a substitution that removes the root!

I was able to find such a substitution
$$x=\frac{9}{15}\cos 2t\Rightarrow \sqrt{15x+9}=3\sqrt{2}\cos t$$
We don't have to put the module, because the restrictions allow us to do so

After we got rid of the root, then comes the second problem. ***How do we solve this equation?***

$$\frac{108}{125}\cos^32 t+\frac{117}{25}\cos^22t-\frac{42}{5}\cos 2t=3-3\sqrt{2}\cos t$$

Comment: $x=0$ is a solution.

Comment: Why does it not make sense to square it? If you square it, you'll find two real solutions, $x=0$ and $x=\frac 34$.

Comment: Can you solve a sixth-degree equation?

Comment: Sometimes you can... In this case, if you search for rational solutions, you'll find the two I mentioned.

Comment: Can you show how you solve a sixth-degree equation?

Isn't it easier to solve the third-degree equation I got after substitution?

Comment: I'm not claiming to be able to solve any sixth degree equation, I'm just saying that I can obtain the real solutions of this particular equation. There is no reason to rule out the possibility of being able solve an equation just because the degree looks to high.

Comment: Okay, can you show me how to solve this sixth-degree equation?

Comment: Once you get that sixth degree and find the rational solutions, you can reduce it to a quartic polynomial.

Comment: Just for an idea: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=4x%5E3%2B13x%5E2-14x%3D3-sqrt%2815x%2B9%29

Comment: If you’re only looking for real solutions, you need $15x+9\ge0$ and $4x^3+13x^2-14x-3\le0$. This tells you that $\frac{-17+\sqrt{241}}{8}\le x\le1$.

Comment: After taking squares, your equation simplifies to  x(4x-3)(4x⁴+29x³+36x²-70x-23)=0, where it is easy to see that the last expression has either 2 or 0 roots by Descartes's rule of signs. It is a simple matter to check f(x)=4x⁴+29x³+36x²-70x-23=0 has two solutions. For example, f(1)=-24<0  and f(2)=277>0. Due to continuity of f(x), one solution must be between 1 and 2.

Comment: You are in luck! Of the four real solutions to $(3-y)^2-(15x+9),y-(4x^3+13x^2-14x)$ which has a primary decomposition `ideal(y,x), ideal(2*y+3,4*x-3), ideal(y^2-15*x-6*y,2*x^2-x*y+14*x-4*y+23)` the two easy ones are the solutions to the original problem. If you change sign on the square root, it's the other two.

Comment: In maple `expand((108*cos(2*t)^3+585*cos(2*t)^2-1050*cos(2*t)+375*sqrt(2)*cos(t)-375)*(1/125)); # (864/125)*cos(t)^6+(1044/125)*cos(t)^4-(3792/125)*cos(t)^2+1152/125+3*2^(1/2)*cos(t)` `subs(cos(t) = y, %); # (864/125)*y^6+(1044/125)*y^4-(3792/125)*y^2+1152/125+3*2^(1/2)*y` `solve(%);` $\frac34\sqrt2>1$ and the equation has two real roots but one is outside $[-1,1].$ `solve(cos(t) = (1/2)*sqrt(2)); # (1/4)*Pi corr. x=0` `solve(cos(t) = -.5048243235); # 2.099974767 corr. x=-0.29` You lose the other solution, because $\frac34 > \frac35 \cos{2t}.$

Comment: After the obvious solution $x=0$ and the less obvious one $x=\tfrac34$ have been identified (perhaps in one of the ways already suggested), one can verify that there are no other real solutions by writing $15x + 9 = y^2$ where $y \geqslant 0,$ cancelling the factor $y - 3,$ and (using hindsight to simplify the arithmetic, although it's not strictly necessary) writing $y = 3t/2$ where $t \geqslant 0$ (or $y = 3u, u = t/2$). The equation for $t$ simplifies to $$(t - 3)(9t^4 + 45t^3 + 258t^2 + 1020t + 1024) = 0,$$ which shows that the only real solution other than $t=2$ ($y=3, x=0$) is $t=3.$

Comment: @Dmitry, You never specified the domain over which you want to solve the equation. All reals? Complex numbers? Complex numbers with only positive real parts? Rationals? Integers?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a way to construct a *possible* solution using only [conjugates](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_(square_roots)) , without applying squaring.

To get *something* useful, we want to multiply both side of the equation by the conjugate $3+\sqrt {15x+9}\neq 0\thinspace $ :

$$\begin{align}x\left(3+\sqrt {15x+9}\right)\left(4x^2+13x-14\right)=-15x\end{align}$$

Since $3+\sqrt {15x+9}\neq 0$ for all $x\geq -\frac 35$, this implies that $x_1=0$ is a solution. Therefore, to find other *possible* roots, we can proceed by dividing both side of the equation by $x\thinspace (x\neq 0\thinspace)$ :

$$
\begin{align}\left(3+\sqrt {15x+9}\right)\left(4x^2+13x-14\right)=-15\end{align}
$$

By rearranging the left-hand side of the equation, we have :

$$
\begin{align}\left(3+\sqrt {15x+9}\right)\left(4x^2+13x-12\right)-2\left(3+\sqrt {15x+9}\right)=-15\end{align}
$$

$$
\begin{align}\left(3+\sqrt {15x+9}\right)\left(4x^2+13x-12\right)=2\sqrt{15x+9}-9\end{align}
$$

Then, multiplying both side of the equation by the conjugate $2\sqrt{15x+9}+9\neq 0\thinspace$, yields :

$$
\begin{align}\left(2\sqrt{15x+9}+9\right)\left(3+\sqrt{15x+9}\right)\left(x+4\right)\left(4x-3\right)=15\left(4x-3\right)\end{align}
$$

Thus, based on the *equivalence* between the mathematical steps, we determine that $x_2=\frac 34$ is the second real root of the original equation, since $\thinspace 4x-3\thinspace$ is the *common* factor of the left and right sides of the equation.

Finally, we need to solve :

$$
\begin{align}\overbrace{\left(9+2\sqrt{15x+9}\right)}^{\ge 9}\thinspace
\overbrace {\left(3+\sqrt {15x+9}\right)}^{\ge 3}\thinspace\overbrace {\left(x+4\right)}^{>3}=15\end{align}
$$

However, we see that the last equation we obtained above has no real roots. Therefore, the original equation has only $2$ real roots : $\thinspace x\in\left\{0,\frac 34\right\}\thinspace.$

This completes the solution.

---

$\rm {Comment:}$

Remember that, this is *not* correct to *generalize* the method we used. The method only works on *specific* instances. Indeed, replace $\sqrt {15x+9}$ with the radical expression $\sqrt {7x+9}$ in the *original* equation, then we will definitely have to apply *squaring* operations and use Galois theory.

Comment: Excellent indeed!

Comment: @NoChance Thank you for your voting .

Answer (score 3):

Rewrite the equation and square both sides:
$$3-4x^3-13x^2+14x=\sqrt{15x+9}$$
$$(3-4x^3-13x^2+14x)^2=16x^6+104x^5+57x^4-388x^3+118x^2+84x+9 $$
You have to solve:
$$16x^6+104x^5+57x^4-388x^3+118x^2+69x=0 $$
which can be factored in the following way:
$$x(4x-3)(4x^4+29x^3+36x^2-70x-23)=0
 $$

Comment: I would like to leave a *little note* for the readers.  In squaring, we need *some restrictions* to ensure equivalence between the mathematical steps.  Therefore, in general, the roots of the *sextic* polynomial are *not* equivalent to the roots of the original equation.  In our case, the possible real roots of the quartic equation are called [extraneous roots](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraneous_and_missing_solutions),  in mathematics.

Comment: @lonestudent Indeed you are right. When squaring, the LHS should be positive, but I didn't wrote that...

Answer (score 2):

The LHS of the equation
$$4x^3+13x^2-14x=3-\sqrt{15x+9}$$
equals $0$ when $x=0$ for which the RHS also equals $0$.

So, here, I would add $ax$ to the both sides (each side still equals $0$ when $x=0$) since after having
$$4x^3+13x^2-14x+ax=ax+3-\sqrt{15x+9}$$
$$4x^3+13x^2-14x+ax=\frac{(ax+3)^2-(15x+9)}{ax+3+\sqrt{15x+9}}$$
$$x(4x^2+13x-14+a)=\frac{x(a^2x+6a-15)}{ax+3+\sqrt{15x+9}}\tag1$$
it may be possible to have something like
$$x(x-c)(\text{something positive})=0$$
if the both sides of $(1)$ have a common factor $(x-c)$.

This means that the solution of $a^2x+6a-15=0$ has to be a solution of $4x^2+13x-14+a=0$, which means that $a$ has to satisfy
$$4\bigg(\frac{-6a+15}{a^2}\bigg)^2+13\bigg(\frac{-6a+15}{a^2}\bigg)-14+a=0$$
i.e.
$$\frac{a^5 - 14 a^4 - 78 a^3 + 339 a^2 - 720 a + 900}{a^4} = 0$$

Fortunately the rational root theorem works to get $a=2$.

---

**Solution** :

$$\begin{align}&4x^3+13x^2-14x=3-\sqrt{15x+9}
\\\\&\iff 4x^3+13x^2-14x+2x=2x+3-\sqrt{15x+9}
\\\\&\iff x(4x-3)(x+4)=\frac{(2x+3)^2-(15x+9)}{2x+3+\sqrt{15x+9}}
\\\\&\iff x(4x-3)(x+4)=\frac{x(4x-3)}{2x+3+\sqrt{15x+9}}
\\\\&\iff x(4x-3)\bigg(x+4-\frac{1}{2x+3+\sqrt{15x+9}}\bigg)=0
\\\\&\iff x(4x-3)\bigg(x+1+3-\frac{1}{2x+3+\sqrt{15x+9}}\bigg)=0
\\\\&\iff x(4x-3)\bigg(\underbrace{x+1+\frac{6(x+1)+2+3\sqrt{15x+9}}{2(x+1)+1+\sqrt{15x+9}}}_{\text{positive since $x\geqslant -9/15\gt -1$}}\bigg)=0
\\\\&\iff x=0,\frac 34\end{align}$$

Comment: I came up with a similar solution as you (only realized after posting, so I deleted mine). For the final step, you could also use: For $ x \geq -\frac{9}{15} > -1$, $(x+4 ) > 3, 2x+3 > 1$,  so $(x+4)(2x+3+\sqrt{15x+9})> 3 > 1$.

Comment: @Calvin Lin : That's a nice idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It *does* make sense to square it.  You do end up with a 6th degree polynomial,

$$16x^6+104x^5+57x^4-388x^3+118x^2+69x=0$$

Then you can use the Rational Root Theorem to restrict the rational solution set to $\pm \frac{\{ 1, 3, 23, 69 \}}{\{ 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 \}}$.  It turns out that only $x = 0$ and $x = \frac{3}{4}$ are valid roots, so you can factor out $x(4x-3)$, giving:

$$4x^4 + 29 x^3 + 36 x^2 - 70 x - 23 = 0$$

[A quartic equation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuarticEquation.html) *can* be solved with a formula, but I don't feel like dealing with the crazy nested radicals, so here are the numerical solutions:

$$x \approx -0.2941828832484235$$
$$x \approx 1.180434322701339$$
$$x \approx -4.068125719726457 \pm 0.09154917260014624i$$

However, only $x = 0$ and $x = \frac{3}{4}$ satisfy the *original* equation $4x^3+13x^2-14x=3-\sqrt{15x+9}$.  The other four roots are extraneous solutions introduced by squaring.

Answer (score 0):

Using *your* hint but working with multiple angles, we end with the problem of finding the zeros of function
$$f(t)=250 \sqrt{2}\,\, | \cos (t)| -646 \cos (2 t)+195 \cos (4 t)+18 \cos (6 t)-55$$ First notice that
$$f(t)=f(\pi-t)$$ Now, the $\sqrt 2$ is quite appealing. So, we have two roots $t=\frac \pi 4$ and $t=\frac {3\pi} 4$.

For sure, what remains is to prove that there is no other solution.